# What's the proper way to implement Fragments in MvvmCross 4.1.4

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am looking for an example or documentation to work with fragments in the current mvvmcross version. I found a lot of information about the old versions but I am confused how I should implement it now.

The best information so far I have found is in this article:
http://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-navigating-android-with-fragments/

But it is over one year old and I think there is already a newer/better way to do it.

What I want is having a single Activity(like in an SPA or having a MainView) this activity should contain one or two fragment and on a button click I want to navigate/change to a different fragment and the current one on the backstack for navigation. Or is it recommend to use only activities for navigation and not implementing a SPA?

Thanks for your help!
Timo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new way to use fragments in MvvmCross is by using attributes on your fragment.

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(ActivityHostViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
public class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<HomeViewModel>
{
}
```

The MvvmCross presenter will recognize that this is a fragment, and show it inside the host activity which is attached to the host viewmodel.

To support fragments in the presenter you need to add the following to your setup.cs

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{
    var mvxFragmentsPresenter = new MvxFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(mvxFragmentsPresenter);
    return mvxFragmentsPresenter;
}
```

A full sample is available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, I have seen this example already but was not sure, if this is currently the proper way to do it. I will take a deeper look into it. :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Hi Martijn00, I have used the sample that you provided on your github. It is quite useful and handy. I am stuck with the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333869/customfragment-in-mvvmcross

Comment: I have asked a new question about this topic at this place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433704/fragments-in-mvvmcross-4-1-4-will-not-be-displayed-in-the-activity-android

Comment: Hi Martijn00, the sample link returns 404, would it be possible to update the link? Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the sample code and understand how it works - when `ShowViewModel(myViewModelType)` is called, it will inject the respective view into the `content_frame`. But what happens when this is done on iOS? Won't it push a new `UIViewController` onto the stack?